# How do I get my regex capturing group to stop excluding portions of my string when using VS 2015 search & replace?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2015, replace

I want to do a Regular Expression search in Visual Studio 2015 for `Me._____ Is Nothing` where ____ does not contain particular text. I also want to turn `Me.______ Is Nothing` (where ___ does not contain a particular phrase) into `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Me.________)`.

```
If Me.Exclude Is Nothing OrElse Not Me.Exclude.Id.HasValue OrElse
    Me.Include1.ToString() Is Nothing OrElse Me.Include2 Is Nothing Then
    ...
End If
```

I tried `(?!.*ExcludeProperty).*((Me.+?)) Is Nothing[^"]` but when I do a replace with `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace($1)` I get this:

```
If Me.Exclude Is Nothing OrElse Not Me.Exclude.Id.HasValue OrElse
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Me.Include2) Then
    ...
End If
```

Instead of this:

```
If Me.Exclude Is Nothing OrElse Not Me.Exclude.Id.HasValue OrElse
 String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Me.Include1.ToString()) OrElse
 String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Me.Include2) Then
        ...
End If
```

How can I include the `Me.Include1` in my capturing group?

Comment: Try [`(Me\.(?:(?!Exclude).)*?) Is Nothing`](https://regex101.com/r/gZUrOg/1) (replace with `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace($1)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a tempered greedy token:

```
(Me\.(?:(?!Exclude).)*?) Is Nothing
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gZUrOg/1)

**Details**:

- `(Me\.(?:(?!Exclude).)*?)` - Group 1 referred to with the `$1` backreference from the replacement pattern later, matching

  - `Me\.`  - a literal char sequence `Me.`
  - `(?:(?!Exclude).)*?` - a tempered greedy token matching any char, 0 or more repetitions, as few as possible, that does not start an `Exclude` char sequence
- `Is Nothing` - a literal char sequence.

Comment: It looks like the second to last parenthesis is in the wrong spot, but this got me close: (Me\.(?:(?!.*Exclude).*?)) Is Nothing[^"]

Comment: Well, in my pattern, no parenthesis is misplaced, `(?:(?!Exclude).)*?` is a kind of a `.*?` pattern but it will stop before each `Exclude`, and thus won't match a string that has `Exclude` in between `Me.` and `Is Nothing`. Mind that `.` does not match CR and LF symbols in VS search and replace feature.